# How to put these frames side to side vertically?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have 3 frames, each one containing 1 image/icon and 1 text label.

I have this code :

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="0">
   <Frame CornerRadius="3" BackgroundColor="#4167b2" HeightRequest="45" Margin="35" Padding="0" HasShadow="false">
   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0" Spacing="0">
      <Image HeightRequest="80" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="https://img.icons8.com/color/120/000000/facebook.png" />
      <Label Text="Login com facebook" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" />
      <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="FacebookButton" AutomationId="FacebookButton" Command="{Binding FacebookButtonCommand}" />
      </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
   </StackLayout>
   </Frame>
   <Frame CornerRadius="3" BackgroundColor="#D44638" HeightRequest="45" Margin="35" Padding="0" HasShadow="false" >
   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0" Spacing="0">
      <Image HeightRequest="80" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="https://img.icons8.com/color/120/000000/gmail.png" />
      <Label Text="Login com g-mail" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" />
      <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="GmailButton" AutomationId="GmailButton" Command="{Binding GmailButtonCommand}" />
      </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
   </StackLayout>
   </Frame>
   <Frame CornerRadius="3" BackgroundColor="#1dcaff" HeightRequest="45" Margin="35" Padding="0" HasShadow="false" >
   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0" Spacing="0">
      <Image HeightRequest="80" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="https://img.icons8.com/color/120/000000/twitter-squared.png" />
      <Label Text="Login com twitter" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" />
      <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="TwitterButton" AutomationId="TwitterButton" Command="{Binding TwitterButtonCommand}" />
      </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
   </StackLayout>
   </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

But it puts the buttons very away from each other. I would like them to be close to each other and in same column. Can anybody help ?

Comment: please include an image that illustrates the problem

Comment: here is an image: https://ibb.co/1MckP3j

Comment: Isn't the Margin=35 for each frame going to ensure that each frame is separated from each other by 70pixels? Try setting Margin="35,0,35,0" (or small value instead of 0 for some separation)

Comment: try setting specific heights on your elements

Comment: When i decreased that value, the image and label for each element also were decreased and couldnt be displayed correctly.

Comment: @Jason on which elements ? Sorry, im newbie.

Comment: nm, you have that on the Frames.  As @PaulF suggests, your margin setting are huge compared to the size of your elements

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you, guys.

Comment: I have added that as an answer below - if you care to mark it as correct it will be of aid to anyone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a very large Margin value (35) on each frame. The Margin is applicable to each element it is specified on - hence you are getting 70pixel spacing between frames (35 + 35 top & bottom).

Rather than specific a a single value which applies all around the element, the Left,Top,Right, Bottom margin/padding can be specified separately as comma separated values (you can have 2 comma separated values for matching left/right & to/bottom spacing too).

Maybe try Margin="35,0,35,0" to retain the left-right spacing & minimise the top-bottom spacing. Note this could be simplified to Margin="35,0" - with this format the 35 applies to left & right, the zero to top & bottom.

There is no reason for top/bottom & left/right to be identical - you can adjust each to get the best effect.

See this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding